# How to compile spark-testing-base in Java project built with maven?

Tags: java, maven, apache-spark, junit

I don't have a lot of experience with Java, but I built a Spark application using Java.
I want to write some unit tests for my Spark application.
I saw that spark-testing-base is very useful for that purpose.
I have added the following to my pom.xml:

> ```
> <dependency>
>     <groupId>com.holdenkarau</groupId>
>     <artifactId>spark-testing-base_2.12</artifactId>
>     <version>2.4.5_1.0.0</version>
>     <scope>test</scope>
> </dependency>
> ```

I'm using Junit framework and my tests fail when trying to reach jsc().
My current test (Not much logic yet):

```
public class SparkTest extends SharedJavaSparkContext {

 @Test
 public void verifyMapTest() {
     // Create and run the test
     List<String> input = Arrays.asList("1\tHeart", "2\tDiamonds");
     JavaRDD<String> inputRDD = jsc().parallelize(input);
 }
}
```

I used the following maven command to build the Jar:
maven clean install

It seems like I didn't really compile spark-testing-base. jsc() returns null and I'm getting null pointer exception.

Comment: Someone can help me with that, please?

Comment: : Did you fixed this issue? I am also facing the same issue. I am getting jsc() as null

Comment: Hi, I was also looking for JUnit 5 capability in the spark-testing-base library a few weeks back and it seems like the library only works for JUnit 4. In the end, I went to write my own JUnit 5 extension and have written a medium article on how to do it.

Article: weikangchia.medium.com/junit-5-spark-testing-bc8eb29b2238

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out the issue for my case.I was using Junit 5 for my test(org.junit.jupiter.api.Test) .And the lib was referring to "org.junit.Test" .If we move to junit4 It will work properly.
Raised an issue with the lib ->https://github.com/holdenk/spark-testing-base/issues/340 .

Hope you also had the same issue.

Comment: Hi, I was also looking for JUnit 5 capability in the spark-testing-base library a few weeks back and it seems like the library only works for JUnit 4. In the end, I went to write my own JUnit 5 extension and have written a medium article on how to do it. Article: weikangchia.medium.com/junit-5-spark-testing-bc8eb29b2238

Answer (score 1):

I was also looking for JUnit 5 capability in the spark-testing-base library a few weeks back and it seems like the library only works for JUnit 4. In the end, I went to write my own JUnit 5 extension and have written a medium article on how to do it.

Article: [weikangchia.medium.com/junit-5-spark-testing-bc8eb29b2238](http://weikangchia.medium.com/junit-5-spark-testing-bc8eb29b2238)